# R: Loop reading and statistic calculations for several variables of multiple .csv files

Tags: r, loops, calculated-columns, read.csv

I am working with R and have several .csv datasets with several parameters (A,B,C,D,E) I want to process.
I want to calculate mean, sd, and other statistic charactaristics for each variable of every dataset and summarize it in a table, so that I can continue working with the data from this point (to create plots, do statistical analysis, etc.).
What I need is a way to read the .csv files individually, as well as calculate the needed values, in a loop, so I don't have to repeat the same thing for every .csv file.

Her are a few example rows of the data I want to process:

```
       Date       A        B              C              D                  E
1      44837.88   11.81    -0.71          0.02           0.03               1453.52
2      44837.88   10.90    -0.71          0.01           0.01               1450.04
3      44837.88   10.22    -0.78          0.02           0.03               1447.37
4      44837.88    9.59    -0.78          0.02           0.03               1444.87
5      44837.88    8.95    -0.85          0.01           0.01               1442.30
```

What I have managed thus far is to read all the .csv files in a loop, and from the imported data create a table with mean, sd, etc. for the single data sets. Now I would like to combine the loop reading with the individual calculation.

Here is the code I used to import the data files. The loop works fine and with that I get an individual data frame for each .csv file.

```
for(i in 1:length(data_files)) {                              
  assign(paste0("data", i),                                 
         read.csv2(paste0("D:\\My\\data\\pathway\\",
                          data_files[i])))
}
```

I also found a way to calculate the stats and summarize them in a table when I use the code for a specific data frame. Thus I can get the data I need by simply putting in the name of the files I received out of the loop.

```
df.sum <- data1 %>%
  select(Temp.C., Depth.m., Salinity.psu., Conduct.mS.cm., Sound.Velocity.m.sec.) %>% # select variables to summarize
  summarise_each(funs(min = min, 
                      q25 = quantile(., 0.25), 
                      median = median, 
                      q75 = quantile(., 0.75), 
                      max = max,
                      mean = mean, 
                      sd = sd))

library(tidyr) #to put the table into the right shape because atm it is still a wide data frame
tidyr::extract

df.stats.tidy <- df.sum %>% gather(stat, val) %>%
  separate(stat, into = c("var", "stat"), sep = "_") %>%
  spread(stat, val) %>%
  select(var, min, q25, median, q75, max, mean, sd)
```

However, this is not yet a very elegant approach, for I don't want to have to copy this code for every single data frame. I can imagine it would also later cause a problem when I want to create plots or do statistical tests and analyses.

Is there a possibility of turning the second code into a loop, so it will just repeat the calculations for every dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `assign`ing to an object in the global environment, create a `list` and do the processing in the `list`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
lst1 <- map(data_files, ~ {
     data1 <- read.csv2(paste0("D:\\My\\data\\pathway\\", .x))
     df.sum <- data1 %>%
  select(Temp.C., Depth.m., Salinity.psu., Conduct.mS.cm., 
      Sound.Velocity.m.sec.) %>% # select variables to summarize
  summarise_each(funs(min = min, 
                      q25 = quantile(., 0.25), 
                      median = median, 
                      q75 = quantile(., 0.75), 
                      max = max,
                      mean = mean, 
                      sd = sd))
   df.stats.tidy <- df.sum %>% gather(stat, val) %>%
  separate(stat, into = c("var", "stat"), sep = "_") %>%
  spread(stat, val) %>%
  select(var, min, q25, median, q75, max, mean, sd) 
  return(df.stats.tidy)


       })
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful! Now for the next step, how can I extract the parameters to compare, for example the mean value of A between the different data frames or create a plot for the mean of A? Do the values already have a coding, or how can I name them respectively?

Comment: @Feli From your code, I don't see any `A` column.  It is just `var, `min, etc columns and the list returns the `df.stats.tidy` dataset

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been more specific. From the code I get var, min, etc. for each parameter (that's what I meant by A,B,C,D,...) of every data frame. Let's say A is temperature, how can I compare the mean temperature of different data frames? For a plot or statistical analysis, I would need to name the categories. That's why I wanted to ask if the values are already given names or if I have to create variables for them?